# Check if child variable value is set

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

I have a long chain of objects and want to check if the last object in the chain is null. Like this:

```
if(obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4) {
    // obj4 is not null --> do stuff
}
```

However if obj3 is null, I get an exception. So I would have to do:

```js
if(obj1.obj2.obj3) {
    // obj3 is not null
    if(obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4) {
        // obj4 is not null --> do stuff
    }
}
```

obj1 and obj2 might be also null, so I have to check these as well. I'm sure there must be a better way to implement this, instead of doing if-chains.

Comment: You don't have to do an if chain, you could add multiple conditions in the first if

Comment: He means `if (obj1 && obj1.obj2 && obj1.obj2.obj3 && obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4)` but that's ugly as sin.  I'd rather see multiple if statements

Comment: As curiosity, some days ago I discovered a new operator in c# 6 that makes exactly this: obj1?.obj2?.obj3?.obj4?. I haven't found it on javascript yet, but to reduce the pyramid use @Archer comment.

Comment: @Marc Sadly not available in JS yet, but I use it regularly in C#.  The 2 languages get closer every update! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can check them with `&&` operator

```
if(obj1 && obj1.obj2 && obj1.obj2.obj3 && obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4) {

}
```